# Google Search Console returning an error that "An HTML tag contains the same attribute repeated twice"

Tags: duplicates, amp-html

Google Console is returning an error that "An HTML tag contains the same attribute repeated multiple times." And I agree. It's the tags I'm using for the header image. But if I remove either one, it breaks the site on mobile devices. What am I doing wrong?

```
<figure class="ampstart-image-fullpage-hero m0 relative mb4">

<amp-img width="404" height="720" alt="Need a roofer" layout="responsive" src="img/need-a-roofer.jpg" alt="Need a Roofer?" media="(max-width: 415px)"></amp-img>

<amp-img** height="720" alt="roofer wichita" layout="fixed-height" src="img/need-a-roofer.jpg" alt="roofer wichita" media="(min-width: 416px)"></amp-img>

<figcaption class="absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0">
```

Comment: By removing one of the **alt attributes** it breaks on mobile? What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: My bad. It doesn't break mobile. It generates an error message on Google My Business that say "An HTML tag contains the same attributes repeated multiple times. Here's the revised code.<amp-img width="404" height="720" alt="Need a roofer" layout="responsive" src="img/need-a-roofer.jpg" media="(max-width: 415px)"></amp-img>
 <amp-img height="720" layout="fixed-height" src="img/need-a-roofer.jpg" alt="roofer wichita" media="(min-width: 416px)"></amp-img>

Comment: one <amp-img> tag has the attribute alt="Need a roofer"    one has the attribute alt="roofer wichita" - don't understand why I'm getting an error that says the AMP code is incorrect

Comment: aha! I got it... silly mistake on my part... I had two alt tags instead of an alt and a title tag...  thanks for your help!!!!!   ...not the world's best coder

Answer (score 1):

Your `amp-img` tags contain two alt attributes. By removing one of the alt attribute from each of the `amp-img` google-console will stop complaining.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that completely fixed the problem. Can't believe I made such a rookie mistake.

Comment: Don't worry - you learn by making mistakes. You will not make the same one a second time ;-)